# Prove that if the sum $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ then, $1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\dots=\frac{3}{4}S$

Tags: calculus, summation

Prove that if the sum $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ then, $1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\dots=\frac{3}{4}S$

**Attempt**:

I did figure out that $1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\dots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$

I have checked on google for $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ and i do not suppose to know that is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

and I checked how The sum can be given explicitly of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$

and the result was show that needs the Fourier series and we haven't learned that yet.

So, I have no idea how to prove that equal to $\frac{3}{4}S$ without know the exactly the sum

Thanks.

Comment: The trick is to relate the unknown sum to a sum that can be evaluated. You achieved the first step - you know the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Now the trick is to relate your sum to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

\begin{align}
S & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} + \frac{1}{4}S
\end{align}

Comment: I think you should be careful showing a solution to a beginner that changes the associativity of the additions in a sum.  It happens to work in this case, but it is notorious for causing problems.  That's why I showed partial sums instead.

Comment: Great answer and beautiful one, I only have one question how did you know to open the sum like that, I hardly understand how I can separate the sums you have any guide or something I can learn?

Comment: Try writing out each sum. You'll see that the sum on the first line as all squares, while the two sums on the second line are the sums of odd squares and the sums of even squares. These are equal because all odd terms plus all even terms equals all terms.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_k = \frac1{1^2} + \frac1{2^2} + \frac1{3^2} + \frac1{4^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$$
$$T_k = \frac1{1^2} + \frac1{3^2} + \frac1{5^2} + \frac1{7^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$$

Look at $\lim_{k \to \infty} {S_k - T_k}$.

Comment: how it possible the $T_k = \frac{1}{1^2} \dots \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$ if we starting the sum from n=1? so it need to be $(2k-1)^2$ how both of the $S_k$ and $T_k$ equals in the end? its not see true

Comment: @Epsilon1 You can let $n=k+1$ if you prefer.  The choice of variable isn't really important.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that you get to this series by subtracting the even $n$ terms from the original.

Further, note that for any $n$,
$$
\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$

Comment: heads up your profile page: nrpeterson.info doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Thank you - long dead, but apparently not forgotten :-)